# Jest shows Assertion Error because React input value does not change with userEvent

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

My `TextInput` component

```
import { ChangeEvent } from 'react';

interface TextInputProps {
  placeholderText: string
  value: string
  onChange: (e: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => void
}

const TextInput = ({ placeholderText, value, onChange }: TextInputProps) => {
  return (
    <input placeholder={placeholderText} type="text" value={value} onChange={onChange} />
  )
}

export { TextInput }
```

My test

```
import { render } from '@testing-library/react';
import userEvent from '@testing-library/user-event';
import { vi } from 'vitest';
import { TextInput } from './TextInput';

describe('TextInput', () => {
  test('should update input value when user types', () => {
    const mockOnChange = vi.fn();
    const { getByPlaceholderText } = render(
      <TextInput placeholderText="Test Placeholder" value="" onChange={mockOnChange} />
    );

    const inputElement = getByPlaceholderText('Test Placeholder') as HTMLInputElement;
    userEvent.type(inputElement, 'Test Input Value');

    expect(inputElement.value).toBe('Test Input Value');
    expect(mockOnChange).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(14);
  });
});
```

My error

```
AssertionError: expected '' to be 'Test Input Value' // Object.is equality
 ❯ src/components/TextInput/TestInput.test.tsx:16:32
     14|     userEvent.type(inputElement, 'Test Input Value');
     15| 
     16|     expect(inputElement.value).toBe('Test Input Value');
       |                                ^
     17|     expect(mockOnChange).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(14);
     18|   });

  - Expected  - 1
  + Received  + 1

  - 'Test Input Value'
  + ''
```

I don't know why `inputElement.value` is not changing after using

```
userEvent.type(inputElement, 'Test Input Value');
```

What am I doing wrong?